# .Net Core: Custom scope for "Scoped" Dependency injection w.out. a controller

Tags: dependency-injection, scope, .net-core, message-queue, amqp

I have an application that does not recieve ordinary HTTP requests through a controller, instead it listens to and receives messages (AMQP protocol) in order to initiate it's logic flow.

My application may receive and handle more than 1 message at a time. I have an object that will be collecting information/data throughout the process, in several different services/classes, in order for me to use it at the end. 
But I need the data to be seperated per message received, as a "Scoped" injection would seperate the injected instance from other HTTP requests.

My usecase is therefor very similar to how I would use a Scoped injected object in an ordinary API, but instead of a new HTTP request, I receive a message in my listeners.

Is there any way that I can create a custom scope, for every message received, either through some kind of configuration, or having the code create a new scope as the first thing in my Listener.MessageReceived(Message message) method?

Imagine a flow like this:

```
public class Listener {
    ServiceClassA serviceClassA //injected in constructor
    CustomLogger customLogger // (HAS TO BE SAME OBJECT INJECTED INTO ServiceClassA, ServiceClassB and Listener)

    public void ReceiveMessage(Message message) {
        using (var scope = CreateNewScope()) {
            try {
                serviceClassA.DoStuff();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Console.Write(customLogger.GetLogs())
            }
        }
    }
}


public class ServiceClassA {
    ServiceClassB serviceClassB //injected in constructor
    CustomLogger customLogger //(HAS TO BE SAME OBJECT INJECTED INTO ServiceClassA, ServiceClassB and Listener)

    public void DoStuff() {
        customLogger = ResolveCustomLogger(); // how do I make sure I can get/resolve the same object as in Listener (without having to pass parameters)
        var data = // does stuff
        customLogger.Log(data);

        serviceClassB.DoStuff();
    }
}


public class ServiceClassB {
    CustomLogger customLogger //(HAS TO BE SAME OBJECT INJECTED INTO ServiceClassA, ServiceClassB and Listener)

    public void DoStuff() {
        customLogger = ResolveCustomLogger(); // how do I make sure I can get/resolve the same object as in Listener (without having to pass parameters)
        var data = // does other stuff
        customLogger.Log(data);
    }
}
```

My CustomLogger may not only be used 1 or 2 service layers down, there might be many layers, and I might only want to use the CustomLogger in the bottom on, yet I want it accessible in the top level afterwards, to retrieve the data stored in it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#resolve-a-scoped-service-within-the-application-scope)?

Comment: @Steven I have seen examples of creating a scope with a using clause, but it seems to me that to create another instance of the same object would require me to pass this "scope object" to that method, in order to create the needed object with that same scope. That is no better that passing my object in the first place, which I would rather avoid. I will extend my original post with an example.

Comment: The trick here is to _not_ inject `serviceClassA` into `Listener`, but to _resolve_ it from the `scope` you create inside `Listener`, and to have `CustomLogger` registeres as `Singleton`.

Comment: @Steven How will I make sure that the CustomLogger that I resolve in serviceClassA is the same object as resolved in the Listener method that called the method of serviceClassA (without passing the scope object)?

Comment: Register `CustomLogger` as Singleton.

Answer (score 7):

You can inject a ServiceScopyFactory in the class that reacts to messages from the queue, then for each message it receives it can create a scope, from which it requests a MessageHandler dependency.

The code sample below does exactly this (and it also deals with sessions on the queue, but that should make no difference for creating the scope).

```
public class SessionHandler : ISessionHandler
{
    public readonly string SessionId;
    private readonly ILogger<SessionHandler> Logger;
    private readonly IServiceScopeFactory ServiceScopeFactory;

    readonly SessionState SessionState;

    public SessionHandler(
        ILogger<SessionHandler> logger,
        IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory,
        string sessionId)
    {
        Logger = logger;
        ServiceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;
        SessionId = sessionId
        SessionState = new SessionState();
    }

    public async Task HandleMessage(IMessageSession session, Message message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Logger.LogInformation($"Message of {message.Body.Length} bytes received.");


        // Deserialize message
        bool deserializationSuccess = TryDeserializeMessageBody(message.Body, out var incomingMessage);

        if (!deserializationSuccess)
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // Move to deadletter queue?


        // Dispatch message
        bool handlingSuccess = await HandleMessageWithScopedHandler(incomingMessage, cancellationToken);

        if (!handlingSuccess)
            throw new NotImplementedException(); // Move to deadletter queue?
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Instantiate a message handler with a service scope that lasts until the message handling is done.
    /// </summary>
    private async Task<bool> HandleMessageWithScopedHandler(IncomingMessage incomingMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            using IServiceScope messageHandlerScope = ServiceScopeFactory.CreateScope();
            var messageHandlerFactory = messageHandlerScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMessageHandlerFactory>();
            var messageHandler = messageHandlerFactory.Create(SessionState);

            await messageHandler.HandleMessage(incomingMessage, cancellationToken);

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Logger.LogError(exception, $"An exception occurred when handling a message: {exception.Message}.");
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool TryDeserializeMessageBody(byte[] body, out IncomingMessage? incomingMessage)
    {
        incomingMessage = null;

        try
        {
            incomingMessage = IncomingMessage.Deserialize(body);
            return true;
        }
        catch (MessageDeserializationException exception)
        {
            Logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);    
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now whenever a MessageHandlerFactory is instantiated (which happens for each message received from the queue), any scoped dependencies requested by the factory will live until the MessageHandler.HandleMessage() task finishes.

I created a message handler factory so that the SessionHandler could pass non-DI-service arguments to the constructor of the MessageHandler (the SessionState object in this case) in addition to the DI-services. It is the factory who requests the (scoped) dependencies and passes them to the MessageHandler. If you are not using sessions then you might not need the factory, and you can instead fetch a MessageHandler from the scope directly.